# What kind of relationship is there, if any, between simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions and chi-squared residuals?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to understand if/how the chi-square test relates to  simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions. It doesn't relate to a practical problem to solve, so this is just a speculative/theoretical question, but please tell me if I'm on a completely wrong track.

Let's say I have a two-way contingency table (i.e. a crosstabulation of two categorical variables), with independent observations.

I run a chi-square test of independence on this table. Besides the chi-square statistic and the omnibus p-value, I also get standardized/adjusted residuals for each cell of this table. As these residuals have a standard normal distribution, I can check if they differ significantly from their expected values under the null hypothesis.

On the other hand, I could say (correct me if I'm wrong!) that this table is also a multinomial distribution of 9 proportions (summing to one), and I could compute simultaneous confidence intervals around these multinomial proportions.

My question is: if the expected proportion of the cell under independence is outside of the range of the multinomial CI, will the residual in this cell always be significant?

If so, can we say that testing residuals and computing multinomial CI are equivalent?

If not, what are some of their fundamental differences?

Thank you for any insight or reference you could give.

Comment: Hi Coris, welcome to CV! This is an interesting and thoughtful question. I could see that you are still unregistered - hope you confirm your account in time, so you are able to interact. (I once posted without confirmation and lost access, since I overlooked the confirmation mail in spam)